# Find duplicates from an array using one for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, duplicates

I want to find duplicates from an array by using only one for loop. I did it by using two for loops. How can I do this in Java?

```
duplicates = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
       if(name[i].equals(name[j])){
          duplicates = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: "I did it by using two for loops. How can I do this in Java?" currently your code is not removing nothing. all it does it set duplicates to true within the for loop.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you provided only sets a flag if it finds duplicates, it does not remove duplicates. Could you expand on your question?

Comment: Why not just use a HashSet? HashSets cannot contain any duplicates. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html. Add all of the values from the array to a HashSet, then add them back.

Comment: @Yapa If you just want to find any duplicate pair and return true. Sort all the elements and compare each with its next element.

Comment: I want to find out what are the duplicates first. So How can I do this using only one for loop without using HashSet or others. That is my target.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. Please put in the effort to ask a clear unambiguous question.

Comment: Make one of the **for** loops a **while** loop, or, use a counter variable in a single for loop, or.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider to use Set, Otherwise You will probably need to do two loops. The below sample won't have a duplicates. Remember that I am not giving you a guarantee that this option has higher performance. performance wise it is better to work in raw arrays than using java collection apis'

```
Set  setString = new LinkedHashSet();

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        setString.add(array[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find out what are the duplicates first. So how can I do this using only one for loop without using `HashSet` or others. That is my target.

It is not possible.

---

Well actually, it is possible if you cheat.

```
int len = array.length;
boolean duplicates = false;
for (int i = 0; i < len * len; i++){
   if (name[i / len].equals(name[i % len])){
       duplicates = true;
   }
}
```

[Look Ma ... only one loop](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-look-ma-no-hands)!

But this is still `O(N^2)` so you haven't really achieved anything ... in practical terms.